# Drupal - installed Events modules (calendar) - Views missing

Tags: events, drupal, calendar, module, view

I installed installed Events (calendar) module, and am able to add events and view events using event and event/list paths, however documentation talks about a default view being provided. I don't have this view and I searched through event module to find it (searched for "$view = new view" in install and elsewhere). Is this available in current version?

info from install module:

```
; $Id: event.info,v 1.5 2008/01/06 14:13:31 killes Exp $
name = Event
description = Calendaring API, calendar display and export
package = Event
core = 6.x

; Information added by drupal.org packaging script on 2010-02-26
version = "6.x-2.x-dev"
core = "6.x"
project = "event"
datestamp = "1267185921"
```

Answer (score 1):

Event Views: Requires both the Event module and the Views module. The Event Views module exposes event fields to the Views module, creates year, month, day, and week argument handlers, and provides default event views that filter events using a drop-down date selector, the jscalendar selector, if installed, or by arguments in the url. Argument combinations can include year, year/month, year/month/day, and year/week. You can also combine the event arguments with content type and taxonomy arguments for more granularity.

**Note that until recently this module was included with the event module's tarball.**

The Drupal 6 version of this module has now been released and works with Views API 2. Currently is supports Views Filters, Views Sorting, Views Arguments, and Views Fields. It also supports Views Relationships for NID.